# Chrome Extension Icon Toggle Only Updates Once

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a toggling function, in background.js: every time a user clicks the icon, if the extension was turned off, it is turned on, and if extension was turned on, is now off, and the icon swaps to reveal which of those states it's in. "image1" revealing that it's turned off and "image2" revealing it's turned on. However, the function only updates icon URL once when clicked, despite the fact that it continually fires from "onclicked" event as evidenced by chrome dev console. Any ideas?

Here is what's in background.js:

```
var off = true;

function updateIcon() {
    if (off == true) {
        off = false;
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"image1.png"});
        console.log(off);
    }
    else {
        off = true;
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"image2.png"});
        console.log(off);
    }
    return;
}
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(updateIcon);
updateIcon();
```

And my manifest.json file:

```
{
   "background": {
      "scripts": [ "jquery-3.1.1.min.js", "background.js" ]
   },
   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "image1.png"
   },
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "css": [ "style.css" ],
      "js": [ "jquery-3.1.1.min.js", "content.js"],
      "matches": [ "https://www.facebook.com/*", "http://www.facebook.com/*", "http://facebook.com/*", "https://facebook.com/*"],
      "all_frames" : true,
      "run_at" : "document_start"
   } ],
   "icons" : {
       "64" : "image1.png",
       "64" : "image2.png"
   },
   "description": "Blah blah blah",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Working Title",
   "permissions": [ "activeTab", "https://www.facebook.com/*", "http://www.facebook.com/*" ],
   "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
   "version": "1.0",
   "web_accessible_resources": [ "images/*.png" ]
}
```

Comment: I checked your code (57.0.2987.133 Win10) and it works fine. It toggles icon on every click.

Comment: I have a suspicion you have a typo in the name of one of your icons. Besides, your `icons` key in the manifest makes little sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Icons were not the proper size of 128 x 128. Working now. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is something wrong with your browser or your computer, but I tested all the code onto different files and it seems to work fine. Unless there is anything clashing with the background.js from the content.js, it isn't the code that's the problem.